# ol.interaction.Draw condition on mouse move?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm using a `ol.interaction.Draw` to draw new features onto a map, but there are also already existing features on the map. I want the user to not be able to place a new feature when the mouse is hovering an existing feature.

For now I use a `condition` on the Draw interaction which returns false when it's set on a pixel where there is already a feature. But when just moving the mouse over these pixels, it's still styled like the user was able to place a marker there. Is there something like `condition` which is checked at every mouse move not just at a click?

Update: my current condition is:

```
condition: function(e) {
  var isFirstOne = true;
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature) {
    var n = feature.get('name');
    // if n is undefined, feature is the current drawing one
    if (!!n) return feature;
  });
  return (!feature);
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code for the `condition` you are using ?

Comment: @HichamZouarhi: I updated the question

Comment: you can change the style of the draw interaction inside your condition, however I couldn't find a predefined function to do that in OL3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something like condition which is checked at every mouse move
>   not just at a click?

Yes, you can use [`pointermove`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html#event:pointermove), and change the cursor (via CSS):

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) return;
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent));
  map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```